# how to pack already installed software in symbain 3rd version?

Tags: python-3.x, symbian3, s60-3rd-edition

in Symbian 2nd Version, there's a software called Sisboom which works with python, with Sisboom it was possible to get the installer file of already installed software, now i've Symbian 3rd Version, and i got the same software, and i'm unbale to do the same, please help...

Answer (score 0):

With Symbian there is something called platform security, and from it there is something called data caging which is preventing access to the executable folders and some other ones as well, thus there are not really possibilities on 3rd party supplying such an application, and therefor I would suppose there would not be application with this kind of functionality available.